# R - 'data' argument is of the wrong type using effect() function to summarise mixed models (lmer) estimate

Tags: r, model, lme4, effect, mixed

I'm quite new to  R, and recently I was tasked to use ggplot to visualise the results of an lmer model. To do so, I'm first trying to summarise and convert the mixed model estimates into a dataframe.

my code:

```
model <- lmer (outcome ~ group*time + (1|ID), data)


model.eff <- effect("group*time", model) #which supposedly summarises the mixed model estimates.
```

But here is where I'm stuck. I keep getting this error message
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :   'data' argument is of the wrong type

After reading around, I gather the problem might lie with the class of my "model", but I'm not sure how to rectify this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is a package "broom" which makes handling model outputs much easier. It simply requires you to enter the model into the function "tidy":

```
library(broom)
model <- 
 lmer (outcome ~ group*time + (1|ID), data)

model.eff <- tidy(model)
```

You will then have an output in this style (example from my data as you didn't provide any example data):

```
  effect   group    term            estimate std.error statistic
1 fixed    NA       (Intercept)        6.14      4.68      1.31 
2 fixed    NA       PFS_days          -0.561     0.573    -0.981
3 ran_pars sex      sd__(Intercept)    1.36     NA        NA    
4 ran_pars Residual sd__Observation    3.50     NA        NA
```